# In tensorflow 1.15.5 / keras, how to use a tensor defined during building as a loss value for tape.gradient

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to change [this](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan/blob/v5.0.0/latplan/network.py#L444) line of a model training :

```
net.train_on_batch(train_subdata_batch_cache, train_subdata_to_batch_cache)
```

Into something like this:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    net(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_subdata_batch_cache, dtype=tf.float32))
    loss_value = self.loss
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, net.trainable_weights)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, net.trainable_weights))
```

Where *self.loss* comes from [here](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan/blob/v5.0.0/latplan/model.py#L1534)

But, when I execute this code, I get:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dtype'

So I also tried to add a new variable in *model.py* (just below l. 1534), namely:

```
self.otherloss = total_loss
```

and then do:

```
loss_value = self.otherloss
```

But this time I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id'

To sum up, I want to take the loss stored in the variable [total_loss](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan/blob/v5.0.0/latplan/model.py#L1511) and use it in my custom training loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the problem is that `net` is the layer of a NN with its own loss cost, and `self.loss` is a function in the class `Network` working as an interface to execute logic of several layers.

I think what you are searching for the loss of a layer which it's in the object `net`, but I am not sure which object is that to get the loss, you can try to use the Keras api to check the loss by:

```py
tf.keras.losses.get(net)
```

Or you can try to check [Tf Keras keep loss of every batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383500/tensorflow-keras-keep-loss-of-every-batch)

If instead you search for the list of the losses of all the layers you can find it in `self.losses`

Comment: thanks for your answer, your other suggestion is maybe the right one, I created this post to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502412/in-keras-how-to-modify-the-loss-at-every-batch-with-extra-code-that-should-be , of course if it work I will validate your answer, cheers

Comment: no problem, let me know if it doesn´t work if I can help you further