# In Keras, how to modify the loss at every batch (with extra code that should be run during training)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using this custom callbacks, I can 1) see the loss during training 2) access to the model being trained

```
class ChangeBatchLoss(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        if 't_loss' in logs:
            print(logs, file=sys.stderr)
            print(self.model, file=sys.stderr)
```

My question is: is it possible to modify the loss itself during training ? (I want to perform some extra calculations and add/substract to the loss (in my code the "loss" corresponds to the value shown by logs["t_loss"].

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to overide `train_step` by subclassing a Keras model.

Comment: @Frightera going to try, thanks

Comment: well, I didnt specify but I am actually using train_on_batch

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom Model for the relevant model
2. override the function _make_train_function and modify self.metrics_tensors or self.total_loss